# Use of undeclared identifier 'AIRGoogleMapOverlay' react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I have done exactly the same installation as described in this link for IOS
https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

But for some reason I am getting these errors:

1. Use of undeclared identifier 'AIRGoogleMapOverlay'
2. Use of undeclared identifier 'overlay'
3. Use of undeclared identifier 'overlay'

The code:
    #import "AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager.h"
    #import "AIRGoogleMapOverlay.h"

```
@interface AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager()

@end

@implementation AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

(UIView *)view
{
  AIRGoogleMapOverlay *overlay = [AIRGoogleMapOverlay new];
  overlay.bridge = self.bridge;
  return overlay;
}

RCT_REMAP_VIEW_PROPERTY(bounds, boundsRect, NSArray)
RCT_REMAP_VIEW_PROPERTY(image, imageSrc, NSString)

@end
```

Answer (score 7):

navigate to your project => Build Setting => Preprocessor Macros section
add HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS=1 to the preprocessor macros

[screenshot_config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpQZa.png)